# Visio 2010 Change double-click action of Master Shape

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to be able to double-click on my shape and add text so the text is associated. This is the behavior of the existing icons.

Answer (score 1):

Load the stencil, right-click the stencil header and select **Edit stencil**. Select the shape you wish to change, right-click and select **Edit master** -> **Edit master shape**. Click the shape to select it, then from the ribbon select **Developer** -> Behavior. Choose the **Double-click** tab and select **Edit shape's text** and select Ok.
Close the shape, save the stencil and close edit mode.

1. If you can't see Developer on the ribbon then you need to enable developer mode (File -> Options -> Advanced)
2. The above instructions are suitable for a simple shape, there are many things that could go wrong:
   a. the master may be more than one shape, and not be grouped.
   b. the shape may have some other action enabled for double-click.
   c. the shape may have its text protected.
   d. any text you do add may be in the wrong location.